# WPF: Difference between binding and real value when it comes to rendering

Tags: wpf

I'm working on a rather big project, that's why I can't really paste working code, but maybe you can give me a hint on what's wrong from reading the symptoms. Otherwise I have to see how I can re-create the problem in a smaller project to paste it in here.

I have a custom control that inherits from `TreeView`, let's call it `MyTreeView`. This control is using its own containers, let's call them `MyTreeViewItem`s.

The whole thing is styled and tweaked that it looks like a family tree or an org chart (horizontally instead of vertically, parents on top, children below). The connecting lines are drawn in the `OnRender` procedure of `MyTreeView`.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnRender(drawingContext As DrawingContext)
    Dim bounds As ItemBounds = Nothing

    If (Me.ConnectorPen IsNot Nothing) Then
        Me.GetItemBounds(Me, bounds)
        Me.DrawConnections(Me.ConnectorPen, drawingContext, bounds)
    End If

    MyBase.OnRender(drawingContext)
End Sub
```

`ConnectorPen` is a dependency property of type `Pen` and `ItemBounds` is a small hierarchical helper class holding the bounding rectangles of the content of all `MyTreeViewItem`s.

`GetItemBounds` collects the bounding rectangles of the content of every `MyTreeViewItem`.

```
Private Sub GetItemBounds(parent As ItemsControl, ByRef bounds As ItemBounds)
    Dim tvi As MyTreeViewItem
    Dim topLeft As Point
    Dim bottomRight As Point
    Dim current As ItemBounds = Nothing

    For Each item As Object In parent.Items
        tvi = TryCast(parent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item), MyTreeViewItem)

        If (tvi IsNot Nothing) Then
            topLeft = tvi.Content.TranslatePoint(New Point(0, 0), Me)
            bottomRight = tvi.Content.TranslatePoint(New Point(tvi.Content.ActualWidth, tvi.Content.ActualHeight), Me)

            If (bounds Is Nothing) Then
                bounds = New ItemBounds
                bounds.Bounds = New Rect(topLeft, bottomRight)
                current = bounds
            Else
                current = New ItemBounds
                current.Bounds = New Rect(topLeft, bottomRight)
                bounds.Children.Add(current)
            End If
        End If

        Me.GetItemBounds(tvi, current)
    Next item
End Sub
```

`tvi.Content` is the `ContentPresenter` holding the content of the current item.

`DrawConnections` draws the connecting lines according to the collected item bounds:

```
Private Sub DrawConnections(p As Pen, drawingContext As DrawingContext, bounds As ItemBounds)
    Dim minChildTop As Double
    Dim middle As Double

    If (bounds Is Nothing) OrElse (bounds.Children Is Nothing) OrElse (bounds.Children.Count = 0) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (bounds.Children.Count > 1) Then
        minChildTop = bounds.Children.Min(Of Double)(Function(x As ItemBounds) x.Bounds.Top)
        middle = bounds.Bounds.Bottom + ((minChildTop - bounds.Bounds.Bottom) / 2)

        drawingContext.DrawLine(p, bounds.Bounds.BottomCenter,
                                   New Point(bounds.Bounds.BottomCenter.X, middle))
        drawingContext.DrawLine(p, New Point(bounds.Children.First.Bounds.TopCenter.X, middle),
                                   New Point(bounds.Children.Last.Bounds.TopCenter.X, middle))
    End If

    For Each item As ItemBounds In bounds.Children
        If (bounds.Children.Count > 1) Then
            drawingContext.DrawLine(p, New Point(item.Bounds.TopCenter.X, middle),
                                       item.Bounds.TopCenter)
        Else
            drawingContext.DrawLine(p, bounds.Bounds.BottomCenter,
                                       item.Bounds.TopCenter)
        End If

        Me.DrawConnections(p, drawingContext, item)
    Next item
End Sub
```

`BottomCenter` and `TopCenter` are extension methods for `Rect` to determine the `Point` which cuts the top edge or the bottom edge into two same-length halves.

Everything works fine so far. The space between one parent item and it's children is created by a fix margin that is added to the `StackPanel`, that is used as the `ItemsPanel` in the default style of `MyTreeViewItem`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            IsItemsHost="True"
                            Margin="0,20,0,0" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ...
</Style>
```

Now the customer wants this space between parent and children to be changeable from outside the control. So I added a dependency property called `ItemSpacing` of type `Double` to `MyTreeView`, and changed the default style of `MyTreeViewItem` to use this property instead of the fixed margin (conversion from `Double` to `Thickness` is done by a converter).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            IsItemsHost="True"
                            Margin="{Binding ItemSpacing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyTreeView}}, Converter=..." />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ...
</Style>
```

Now the child items use the space provided by `ItemSpacing` (so that works), but the drawing of the connecting lines fails. It looks like the collecting of the bounding rectangles of the content of all `MyTreeViewItem`s is done before this bound margin is applied.

I already tried to play around with the `AffectsRender` and `AffectsArrange` settings of the `ItemSpacing` dependency property, but that didn't help.

Can you tell me, why this is working with a fix margin and why it isn't working when the margin comes from a binding?

Comment: Could you show the `OnRender`? I have managed to reproduce your code based on the description, but the issue is not present.

Comment: Put some more code in the description.